# How to Retrieve Numeric Column value from SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, calculated-column

In the SharePoint list I am having the numeric column and the value is like this

123,456,789,012,346,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.

I am using SPQuery to retrieve items from the list.  The following code is used for getting the column type

```
reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(field.SchemaXml));
doc = new XmlDocument();
node = doc.ReadNode(reader);
if(item[field.Id] != null)
value = Convert.ToString(item[field.Id]);
```

I am getting the value as **1.02233335552222E+39** how could I get the actual value from the SharePoint list.

The field.schema.xml for the number column looks like this

`"<Field Type="Number" DisplayName="Num Col" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" ID="{339280b6-4b74-45cb-9499-3a986c9d4c34}" SourceID="{16061cf5-90bb-406f-8c87-3bbf667bbbc7}" StaticName="Num_x0020_Col" Name="Num_x0020_Col" ColName="float1" RowOrdinal="0"/>"`

With the help of schema.xml I'm not able to retrieve the actual value from the SharePoint list? Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

That is the 'actual' value (or at least as close as you can get using doule precision floating point data types) - its just in a different notation to normal decimal because its so large.

E.g.

```
1.234E+6 = 1,234,000
```

(moved the decimal point +6 places to the right)

```
1.234E-6 = 0.000001234
```

(and -6 places to the left)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

If you want to read this in .net then see [SO - Convert from scientific notation string to float in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639/convert-from-scientific-notation-string-to-float-in-c-sharp)

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("1.2345E-02", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```